# Reasons why LookUp would not work - report builder 3.0

Tags: reporting-services, lookup, reportbuilder3.0

It's not the first that I'm using this function, but for unknown reasons to me it doesn'T work in this instance. My formula is as follows:

```
=Lookup(Fields!No__dossier.Value, Fields!Dossier_détail.Value, Fields!DMS_jours.Value, "DMS")
```

My source key is:

> Fields!No__dossier.Value

Btw it the data in this fields looks like this: 12345.

My destination key is:

> Fields!Dossier_détail.Value

The data in this field looks like 12345 too, so no difference in it's format.

My actual data that I want to return from the Lookup is:

> Fields!DMS_jours.Value

Finally, the dataset where I'm returning the data from is:

> "DMS"

As mentionned above, it seems to me that my key's format is identical, and the formula is correct, but once I run the report I get blank fields in that column. Can any1 plz hint me what could be the cause of the malfunction? Thanks a lot!!

P.S. I'm using Lookup function in that same tablix but at another column with another source and it works perfectly.

Comment: Can you post the `create table` script for both tables?  It sounds like you may have a data type mismatch.

Comment: Second that @iamdave. Quick test just proved that if the data types of the source and destination key (as the OP refers to them) are not the same, the lookup returns nothing

Comment: @iamdave I apologize for my ''noobness'' but I searched, Googled and all, and I don't know where to find the "create table script" to which both of you refer to! I created them with the Table Wizard =| Are you refering to the codes that are accessible by Right-click on Dataset/DataSet properties/fx? Thank you!

Comment: @Paul Bambury Yeesss! Thanks Paul, I just converted both the source and the destination keys to "Str" and it worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MaxS.  The `create table` script comes from viewing your database via SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and right clicking on the table and selecting `Script As...` -->  `Create To...`.  Given that the conversion mentioned by Paul works for you means that one of your tables is storing that ID field as a number and the other is storing it as a String.  You would be best advised to fix this in your database structure if possible.

Comment: @iamdave Thanks a lot Dave, I asked my IT service to install that app on my PC and I'll definitely dig into that once done!

Comment: @PaulBambury That deserves an answer.